# WordPress RewriteRule - Avoid Partial Matches

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm converting a ColdFusion website to WordPress.  It's all static content, so that's not an issue.

I'm trying to set up the 301 redirects (currently a 302 during testing) for the search engines to remap the pages.  I've created the following, which works 90%.

The problem is that if I do a redirect on a file name that partially matches another page, then it finds and redirects to a partial match.

For example:

`http://www.example.com/a/b/c/this-doesnt-exist.cfm` properly redirects to:
`http://www.example.com/a/b/c/this-doesnt-exist/` with a 404 error.  That's fine.

BUT:

`http://www.example.com/blah/blah/asdf/r23af/b.cfm` redirects to:
`http://www.example.com/blog/`

Basically, it is stripping the `.cfm` and doing a partial match on the file name `b`

How can I get this to avoid partial matches - which creates unpredictable redirects (for example, we have 50 directories that all have a `index.cfm` file and they should only go to the right page in the right folder, not one common `/index/` file)

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(cfm)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.cfm$  /$1/ [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

Comment: I think you need to add `Options -MultiViews` to the htaccess. Otherwise, I think it is a WP problem.

Comment: ¿Where is the WP blog, at `http://www.example.com/blog/` or at `http://www.example.com/`?